# Spring SPEL default @Value from class field/member

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

How to set @Value default from class field/member ?
I have a Spring @Bean class with a @Value annotated field and I need that the default value for that field will come from a class member/field value.
In my example I need the maxNumOfThreads field get its default value from the DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

   @Value("${jobs.max-num-of-threads:....??..}") // <<== howto ?
   private Integer maxNumOfThreads;

   public final Integer DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS = 10;
}
```

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Class field default value can be references using the spel '@' bean reference  syntax: @beanName.fieldName

e.g.: when the bean name is 'AppConfig' and the field we need to reference is
DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS
use `@appConfig` as the bean name (class name AppConfig starts with lowercase) dot '.' the field name.
bymeans: `@appConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS`

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

   @Value("#{'${jobs.max-num-of-threads:}' ?: @appConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS}")
   private Integer maxNumOfThreads;

   public final Integer DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_OF_THREADS = 10;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
       System.out.println("@PostConstruct init() - in.");
   }
}
```

by yl.

Comment: I like your solution!